# sql get average salary in self reference table

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, hierarchy

I've seen several questions/answers on how to recursively query a self-referencing table, but I am struggling to apply the answers I've found to aggregate up to each parent, grandparent, etc. regardless of where the item sits in the hierarchy.

Need to get an average salary for each department including hierarchy.
It means department should include the average salary of each sub-department and so on.

I've got nex db schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL ,
      Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
      Department_Id INT NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
    ); 

CREATE TABLE Department
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL ,
      DepartmentName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
      Parent_Id INT ,
      PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
    );

CREATE TABLE Salary
    (
      Id INT NOT NULL ,
      Date DATETIME NOT NULL ,
      Amount INT NOT NULL ,
      Employee_Id INT NOT NULL ,
      PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
    );
```

I've tried something like that but it includes only 1st level of a hierarchy.

```
SELECT  d.Id ,
        d.DepartmentName ,
        ( SELECT    AVG(s.Amount)
                FROM      dbo.Department dd
                        LEFT JOIN dbo.Department sdd ON dd.Id = sdd.Parent_Id 
                        JOIN dbo.Employee e ON e.Department_Id = sdd.Id
                                                OR e.Department_Id = dd.Id
                        JOIN dbo.Salary s ON s.Employee_Id = e.Id
                                                WHERE dd.Id = d.Id
        ) AS avg_dep_salary 
FROM    dbo.Department d
WHERE   d.Parent_Id IS NULL;
```

How can get an average salary of all levels?

**EDIT:** Added some inserts

```
INSERT  INTO Employee
        ( Id, Name, Department_Id )
VALUES  ( 1, 'Peter', 1 ),
        ( 2, 'Alex', 1 ),
        ( 3, 'Sam', 2 ),
        ( 4, 'James', 2 ),
        ( 5, 'Anna', 3 ),
        ( 6, 'Susan', 3 ),
        ( 7, 'Abby', 4 ),
        ( 8, 'Endy', 4 );

INSERT  INTO Department
        ( Id, DepartmentName, Parent_Id )
VALUES  ( 1, 'IT', NULL ),
        ( 2, 'HR', NULL),
        ( 3, 'SubIT', 1 ),
        ( 4, 'SubSubIT', 3 );

INSERT  INTO Salary
        ( Id, Date, Amount, Employee_Id )
VALUES  ( 1, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 3000, 1 ),
        ( 2, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 5000, 2 ),
        ( 3, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 2000, 3 ),
        ( 4, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 1000, 4 ),
        ( 5, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 4000, 5 ),
        ( 6, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 6000, 6 ),
        ( 7, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 7000, 7 ),
        ( 8, '2013-01-13 16:03:50.003', 9000, 8 );
```

**Expected result is:**

```
Department | Average_Salary
__________________________________
IT         |  ( X1 + X2 + X3 ) / 3
HR         |  ( Y1 ) / 1
SubIT      |  ( X2 + X3 ) / 2
SubSubIT   |  ( X3 ) / 1
```

Where:

- X1 - Average salary of IT department
- X2 - Average salary of SubIT department
- X3 - Average salary of SubSubIT department
- Y1 - Average
  salary of HR department

Comment: Great you included create statements, could you also add some inserts for some sample data, and the expected result for that sample set?

Comment: Have you tried to union your results then average them

Comment: recursive CTE may help here

Comment: Added inserts and expected result as you asked for :)

Comment: how is this accurate - IT         |  ( X1+ X2 + X3 ) / 3 - wouldn't it be weighted based on the department size?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample data**

I've added few rows with a wider tree structure.

```
DECLARE @Employee TABLE
(
Id INT NOT NULL ,
Name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
Department_Id INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
); 

DECLARE @Department TABLE
(
Id INT NOT NULL ,
DepartmentName VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL ,
Parent_Id INT ,
PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
);

DECLARE @Salary TABLE
(
Id INT NOT NULL ,
Date DATETIME NOT NULL ,
Amount INT NOT NULL ,
Employee_Id INT NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY ( Id )
);

INSERT  INTO @Employee
( Id, Name, Department_Id )
VALUES  
( 1, 'Peter', 1 ),
( 2, 'Alex',  1 ),
( 3, 'Sam',   2 ),
( 4, 'James', 2 ),
( 5, 'Anna',  3 ),
( 6, 'Susan', 3 ),
( 7, 'Abby',  4 ),
( 8, 'Endy',  4 ),
(10, 'e_A',   10),
(11, 'e_AB',  11),
(12, 'e_AC',  12),
(13, 'e_AD',  13),
(14, 'e_ACE', 14),
(15, 'e_ACF', 15),
(16, 'e_ACG', 16);

INSERT  INTO @Department
( Id, DepartmentName, Parent_Id )
VALUES  
( 1, 'IT', NULL ),
( 2, 'HR', NULL),
( 3, 'SubIT', 1 ),
( 4, 'SubSubIT', 3 ),
(10, 'A', NULL ),
(11, 'AB', 10),
(12, 'AC', 10),
(13, 'AD', 10),
(14, 'ACE', 12),
(15, 'ACF', 12),
(16, 'ACG', 12);

INSERT  INTO @Salary
( Id, Date, Amount, Employee_Id )
VALUES  
( 1, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 3000, 1 ),
( 2, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 5000, 2 ),
( 3, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 2000, 3 ),
( 4, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 1000, 4 ),
( 5, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 4000, 5 ),
( 6, '2013-01-11 16:03:50.003', 6000, 6 ),
( 7, '2013-01-09 16:03:50.003', 7000, 7 ),
( 8, '2013-01-13 16:03:50.003', 9000, 8 ),
(10, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 10),
(11, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 11),
(12, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 12),
(13, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 13),
(14, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 14),
(15, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 15),
(16, '2013-01-13 16:03:50', 100, 16);
```

**Query**

```
WITH
CTE_Departments
AS
(
    SELECT
        D.Id
        ,D.Parent_Id
        ,D.DepartmentName
        ,SUM(Amount) AS DepartmentAmount
        ,COUNT(*) AS DepartmentCount
    FROM
        @Department AS D
        INNER JOIN @Employee AS E ON E.Department_Id = D.Id
        INNER JOIN @Salary AS S ON S.Employee_Id = E.Id
    GROUP BY
        D.Id
        ,D.Parent_Id
        ,D.DepartmentName
)
,CTE_Recursive
AS
(
    SELECT
         CTE_Departments.Id AS OriginalID
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentName AS OriginalName
        ,CTE_Departments.Id
        ,CTE_Departments.Parent_Id
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentName
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentAmount
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentCount
        ,1 AS Lvl
    FROM CTE_Departments

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         CTE_Recursive.OriginalID
        ,CTE_Recursive.OriginalName
        ,CTE_Departments.Id
        ,CTE_Departments.Parent_Id
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentName
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentAmount
        ,CTE_Departments.DepartmentCount
        ,CTE_Recursive.Lvl + 1 AS Lvl
    FROM
        CTE_Departments
        INNER JOIN CTE_Recursive ON CTE_Recursive.Id = CTE_Departments.Parent_Id
)
SELECT
    OriginalID
    ,OriginalName
    ,SUM(DepartmentAmount) AS SumAmount
    ,SUM(DepartmentCount) AS SumCount
    ,SUM(DepartmentAmount) / SUM(DepartmentCount) AS AvgAmount
FROM CTE_Recursive
GROUP BY
    OriginalID
    ,OriginalName
ORDER BY OriginalID
;
```

**Result**

```
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
| OriginalID | OriginalName | SumAmount | SumCount | AvgAmount |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
|          1 | IT           |     34000 |        6 |      5666 |
|          2 | HR           |      3000 |        2 |      1500 |
|          3 | SubIT        |     26000 |        4 |      6500 |
|          4 | SubSubIT     |     16000 |        2 |      8000 |
|         10 | A            |       700 |        7 |       100 |
|         11 | AB           |       100 |        1 |       100 |
|         12 | AC           |       400 |        4 |       100 |
|         13 | AD           |       100 |        1 |       100 |
|         14 | ACE          |       100 |        1 |       100 |
|         15 | ACF          |       100 |        1 |       100 |
|         16 | ACG          |       100 |        1 |       100 |
+------------+--------------+-----------+----------+-----------+
```

Run the query step-by-step, CTE-by-CTE to understand how it works.

`CTE_Departments` gives total amount and number of people for each department.

`CTE_Recursive` recursively generates child rows for each department, while keeping the `OriginalID` - the ID of the department where the recursion started.

Final query simply groups everything by this `OriginalID`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way

```
with avg_per_dep as (
    select
        [Month] = eomonth(s.date), d.Id, d.DepartmentName
        , avgDep = avg(s.Amount * 1.0)
    from 
        Salary s
        join Employee e on s.Employee_Id = e.Id
        join Department d on e.Department_Id = d.Id
    group by d.Id, d.DepartmentName, eomonth(s.date)
)
, rcte as (
    select
        i = Id, Id
        , list = cast(',' + cast(Id as varchar(10)) + ',' as varchar(max))
        , step = 1
    from 
        Department
    union all
    select
        a.i, b.Id, cast(a.list + cast(b.Id as varchar(10)) + ',' as varchar(max))
        , step + 1
    from
        rcte a
        join Department b on a.Id = b.Parent_Id
)
select
    d.DepartmentName, c.[Month]
    , Average_Salary = avg(c.avgDep)
from
    (
        select
            top 1 with ties i, list 
        from 
            rcte
        order by row_number() over (partition by i order by step desc)
    ) t
    join avg_per_dep c on t.list like '%,' + cast(c.Id as varchar(10)) + ',%'
    join Department d on t.i = d.Id
group by t.i, d.DepartmentName, c.[Month]
```

Output

```
DepartmentName    [Month]       Average_Salary
---------------------------------------------
IT                2013-01-31    5666.666666
HR                2013-01-31    1500.000000
SubIT             2013-01-31    6500.000000
SubSubIT          2013-01-31    8000.000000
```

Idea:

1. Calculate average salary per department
2. Get a list of departments with all childs with recursive CTE.
3. Join two table and calculate avg with childs

Answer (score 1):

You could also use below query to get the expected result

```
WITH Department_Path 
     AS (SELECT Id, CAST(CONCAT('@', Id, '@') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path 
         FROM   Department 
         WHERE  Parent_Id IS NULL 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT Child.Id, CAST(CONCAT(Parent.Path, Child.Id, '@') AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path 
         FROM   Department Child 
                INNER JOIN Department_Path Parent 
                        ON Parent.Id = Child.Parent_Id) 
SELECT Department.Id, 
       Department.DepartmentName, 
       AVG(Salary.Amount) As Average_Salary, 
       COUNT(Employee.Id) AS Employee_Count 
FROM   Department 
       INNER JOIN Department_Path 
               ON CHARINDEX(CONCAT('@', Department.Id, '@'), Department_Path.Path) > 0 
       INNER JOIN Employee 
               ON Employee.Department_Id = Department_Path.Id 
       INNER JOIN Salary 
               ON Salary.Employee_Id = Employee.Id 
GROUP  BY Department.Id, 
          Department.DepartmentName;
```

The idea is that each employee is belong to a list of hierarchy departments. For each department, we could retrieve all employee who belong to it and then calculate the average salary.